# Pass UDT to RtlMoveMemory as reference to reference

Tags: vb6

I have many repeated constructions as `Construction_1` in class module.
And I want to replace them with `Construction_2` with common sub procedure `RMM`.
However, I am concerned about:
**is it right to pass to RtlMoveMemory 
not direct reference to UDT but ref to ref**
to it as a 'Destination' parameter?
.
**Add:** `y_UDT` is fixed length and `uUDT` passed to `RMM` `As y_UDT`, not `As Variant`

```
' Class module
Option Explicit
'
Private Type y_UDT
    VarLng As Long
    VarByt As Byte
    VarFst As String * 16
End Type

Private Declare Sub RtlMoveMemory Lib "Kernel32" ( _
                    ByRef Destination As Any, _
                    ByRef Source As Any, _
                    ByVal Length&)

' ...

'<--- Construction_1
    ' code before
    '
    lpUDT = SomeCalculations(vSrcData_xx)
    Call RtlMoveMemory(uUDT_xx, ByVal lpUDT, ByVal UDTLENB)  
    '
    ' code after
'--->

' ...

'<--- Construction_2
    Call Sub RMM(uUDT_xx, vSrcData_xx)
'--->

' ...

Sub RMM(ByRef uUDT As y_UDT, ByVal vSrcData As Variant)
Dim lpUDT As Long
'<--- 
    ' code before
    '
    lpUDT = SomeCalculations(vSrcData)
    Call RtlMoveMemory(uUDT, ByVal lpUDT, ByVal UDTLENB)  
    '
    ' code after
'--->
End Sub
```

Comment: You should tidy up your tags and make clear which language you use: VBA is very different from VB6. Also pleas clarify if you use Excel, Access OR Word to run this code if it is VBA.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ It seems me that first of all you should pay attention to answer on the question, but not to the tags qty. In second, it wil be very kind of you if you can specify the differneces of RMM and/or UDT behavior in mentioned languages. If, of course, my tags are really wrong =) Бу-га-га, типо...

Comment: @braX Read the comment above and return all my original tags back.

Comment: you might want to take the [tour] and read [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). This is not how you should behave here especially when you expect help from people here.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ you might want to have any specific knowledge in languages you try speak. My question applies equally to all the languages as VB6 and VBA-family. It is entitled to be marked by any of these tags and, accordingly, by all of them at once.

Comment: To give you an example: This code won't run in Office 64-bit version. Therefore it is absolutely necessary to know the environment (you run that code in) as detailed as possible. Nobody here wants to waste his time to test this in VBA if you actually plan to use this in VB6. At least 3 other people thought that (as you can see on the voting). Maybe you didn't think about that, but that's no reason to be insulting to anyone here. I can only repeat if you want help from people be nice to them.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ* This code won't run in Office 64-bit version. 
- It won't run on Win-64 at all :)

* it is absolutely necessary to know the environment
- the only that it is absolutely necessary to KNOW are nuances in RMM & UDT behavoirs in current interconnection

* waste his time to test this
- I asked for knowlege, but not tests

* you actually plan to use this in VB6
- this part of code will be exported to Acs-2003 mdb dao too, but it is not significant.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ * At least 3 other people - I see, that at least 4 people are very great connoisseurs on tags, but do not know anything on the theme :)) Бу-га-га

Comment: We moved over 100,000 lines of code from VBA to VB6, and it all compiled (and worked), with only minor issues. So the languages are _very_ similar. Yes, VB6 won't run natively in Win64. But Windows has 32-bit compatibility, so what's the issue? In 64-bit Office, VBA7 requires minor rewrites to successfully use 64-bit system calls, mainly LongLong, LongPtr, and PtrSafe declares. But if you don't see the 64-bit specific stuff, you are pretty safe in the assumption that it will work in either language in 32-bits. So again, what's the issue?

Comment: @kismert I did not touch on the theme of compatibility with x64. But Pᴇʜ turn on this context as the reason, that I can't use VBA-related tags :))) Бу-га-га

Answer (score 0):

In the usage examples I found in our code, the `RtlMoveMemory` `Destination` parameter is a direct reference to the UDT, and the `Source` parameter is a pointer to another UDT.

Comment: Does it means that approach I asked is wrong? Or it means only that the precedents are unknown? I implemented 'Construction_2'. Normal flight. However I see it on the short incoming data set that Is wellknown by eyes. Befor final implementing I will try to compare everytime UDTs created by both of constructions.

Comment: Without actually setting up sample code to double-check it, it looks like your code will work. But there has to be a lot of examples on the web on how to use RtlMoveMemory with VB6.